# Displaying GridView at Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I would like to manually add rows to a GridView, and display it at Page Load. For some reason, my current code shows an empty GridView.

**Default.aspx**

```
     <asp:GridView ID="AllocationGridView" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        Width="691px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True"
                        AutoPostBack="true">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" Height="2px" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Asset Class">
                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="20%" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="AssetLabel" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text="" BorderWidth="0px"
                                        Style="text-align: left;"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weight">
                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="20%" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="WeightTextBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" BorderWidth="0px"
                                        Style="text-align: left;"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#EBEBEB" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="10px" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FirstAllocationGridViewRow();
        }           

    }

    protected void FirstAllocationGridViewRow()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        string[] assets = new string[] { "Cash", "US Equity", "Fixed Income", "BAS", "International" };

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(double)));

        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();

   
        for (int i = 0; i < assets.Count(); i++)
        {
            dr = table.NewRow();

            dr["Col1"] = assets[i];
            dr["Col2"] = DBNull.Value;

            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        ViewState["currentAllocationTable"] = table;

        AllocationGridView.Visible = true;
        AllocationGridView.DataSource = table;
        AllocationGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Not sure what you mean, sorry. The two controls used in the GridView are a Label and a TextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your cs code is **fine** the problem is in your layout code. **text property is not bind to table field name**

```
Text='<%# Bind("Col1") %>'
```

here is the complete gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="AllocationGridView" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    Width="691px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True"
                    AutoPostBack="true">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" Height="2px" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Asset Class">
                            <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="20%" />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="AssetLabel" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Bind("Col1") %>' BorderWidth="0px"
                                    Style="text-align: left;"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weight">
                            <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="20%" />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="WeightTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Col2") %>' ReadOnly="true" BorderWidth="0px"
                                    Style="text-align: left;"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#EBEBEB" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="10px" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Remove` the `AutoPostBack="true"` field in `Gridview` control. And make sure the Data-table have correct values for the columns and please see `Text=""` in your `gridview` labels . You need give values for the labels.

See this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1805422.aspx?How%20to%20create%20a%20flipcart%20like%20panel%20for%20showing%20products%20in%20gridview) , It's may helps you

Comment: I am a beginner at asp.net, and I am sure I am following what you are suggesting.. Could you please give a code snapshot for your suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: I have added: `Text='<%# Eval("Col1") %>'` and `'Text='<%# Eval("Col2") %>'` to the Label and TextBox respectively in the GridView, and now it works! Is that what you meant?

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is with your Template Fields as you cannot set values to them using a DataTable, change them to BoundFields or set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`
Tried your code with my answer, it worked fine.